# Dynamic Casting of data from one table to another using SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-cast, dynamicquery

I have a store procedure which is fetching column details of a table. Say this table name is Invoice table.  I have another table, Invoice_Staging table, which has data in varchar format. Now I wish to fetch data from Invoice_staging, cast the values as per data types mentioned in Invoice table and do a bulk insert into Invoice table. Now, by chance, there is a value whose Casting isn't possible, in this case, I don't want my bulk insert to fail. Rather make that particular field NULL and insert it in the Invoice table.
I am stuck with fetching the data and casting them as required. Kindly show me a way, which could throw a lime light on my issue. The stored procedure is as follows -

```
create PROCEDURE usp_stagingToProduction
@staging_tableName varchar(200),
@master_tableName varchar(200)
```

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
Declare @count int, -- for counting the total number of records in a table 
@RowCount int,
@columnName varchar(200),
@columnDataTypeName varchar(200),
@maxLength int,
@precision int,
@scale int,
@isNullable int,
@primaryKey int,
@sql varchar(5000)
Set @sql = ''

    create table #MyTemporaryTable
    (
        ColumnName varchar(500),
        DataType varchar(100),
        MaxLength int,
        [Precision] int,
        Scale int,
        IsNullable bit,
        PrimaryKey bit,
        flag bit default 0,
        id int identity(1,1)
    )

    insert into #MyTemporaryTable
    SELECT 
            c.name 'ColumnName',
            t.Name 'DataType',
            c.max_length  'MaxLength',
            c.precision 'Precision',
            c.scale 'Scale',
            c.is_nullable 'IsNullable',
            ISNULL(i.is_primary_key, 0) 'PrimaryKey',
            0
        FROM    
            sys.columns c
        INNER JOIN 
            sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
        WHERE
            c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('Invoice')

        -- select * from #MyTemporaryTable  -- To display the content of temporary table


        declare @column varchar(500)
        declare @datatype varchar(500)
        declare @id int
        Set @sql = @sql + 'Insert Into ' + @master_tableName
        Set @sql = @sql + ' Select '
        while exists (select Top 1 * from #MyTemporaryTable where flag  = 0)
        BEGIN
            Select @id = id, @datatype = DataType, @column = ColumnName from #MyTemporaryTable Where flag = 0
            Set @sql = @sql + ' Cast(' + @column + ' As ' + @datatype + '), ' -- building the cast query


            update #MyTemporaryTable
            set flag = 1
            where id = @id

            -- Select @sql -- to see whats happing
        END
        Select @sql = SubString(@sql, 1, LEN(@sql) - 1)
        Set @sql = @sql + ' From' +' ' + @staging_tableName  -- #MyTemporaryTable'

        Select @sql -- just to display query. nothing to do anything with the logic 

        -------------------
        select @count = count(*) from @staging_tableName -- getting column count from staging table
        declare @counter as int
        set @counter = 1
        if(@count >0)
             -- data found in staging table
             -- logic here for casting and inserting the data to the table

        else
```

END
GO

--usp_usp_stagingToProduction 'Invoice'

Comment: The SP seems to be truncated. If you have the ability to modify the tables you should think about changing to staging table to be identical to the Invoice table, or made of varchar only

Comment: Why don't you change the data types in staging tables itself & run this SP to bulk insert data. It would be much easier. Or you just write another SP which will check for values that are not able to cast, make them as null in staging itself & call these  both SP's from your master SP.